# User-defined function on sort

Tags: javascript

What is the issue with the following code I have in trying to define my own function to sort by?

```js
let a = ['name', 'age'];
console.log(a);
a.sort((x,y)=>x-y); // whyoesn't this sort properly?
console.log(a);
a.sort();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: what do you expect `"name" - "age"` to return so that `a` would be sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to subtract strings; you get `NaN` unless both operands can be converted to a number. You can instead use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for the comparator.

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given string in sort order.

```js
let a = ['name', 'age'];
a.sort((x, y) => x.localeCompare(y));
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

`x-y` returns `NaN` and isn'g good for string comparisons. Try doing something like:

```js
let a = ['name', 'age'];
console.log(a);
a.sort((x,y)=>x===y?0:x>y?1:-1); // whyoesn't this sort properly?
console.log(a);
a.sort();
console.log(a);
```